# php script to force download of xml file

Tags: php, xml, download

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/force-download; name=\"test.gpx");
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"test.gpx");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
echo (readfile("test.gpx"));
?>
```

The PHP code forces the browser to download a .gpx file.  The mime type is text/xml. The file is always named test.gpx and the file is always in the same folder as the php file.
The code works fine except that it adds the following lines to the end of the file that is downloaded.

```
251980
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->"
```

What is causing the extra lines of text to be added and how can I prevent that. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: looks like something from Hosting24 is adding analytics code, that's something to look into

Answer (score 0):

This is a hosting24 issue. It adds analytics code to (nearly) all files. You could try to "trick it" by changing the Content-Type to "application/xml", which off course isn't entirely correct, but could avoid the analytics add.

Comment: I switched the content type to application/xml but it didn't change anything.  Is there a different approach that will download a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Hosting24 has an option to disable the tracking code, see link below. That fixed the problem for me.  It still inserted the number "251980" at the end of the gpx file but I think that might be ok.  If anybody has any suggestion for getting rid of the 251980 I please let me know.

[link to disable analytics code at hosting24 -aka- 000webhost](http://members.000webhost.com/analytics.php)